# How to get RSCP, SINR and EcNo values in Android

Tags: android, gsm, telecommunication, lte, cdma

I need to find `RSCP`, `SINR` and `EcNo`. So far i am able to calculate `RSRP` and `RSRQ` values from [android.telephony.SignalStrength](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength.html).

My questions are:

1. When I try to get `SignalStrength#getTdScdmaDbm()` via reflection it
   returns `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (if i debug at [line 300](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/369808638bcdf90a2e4723cbd728aa29e2f4a051/telephony/java/android/telephony/SignalStrength.java#300) its value
   is    0)
          According to [AOSP RIL (Radio Interface Layer)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/ril/+/master/include/telephony/ril.h#1302)

   > The Received Signal Code Power in dBm multipled by -1. Range :
   >   25 to 120, INT_MAX: 0x7FFFFFFF denotes invalid value.  Reference:
   >   3GPP TS 25.123, section 9.1.1.1
2. Is there any other way to calculate `RSCP`.
3. `EcNo = RSCP / RSSI` where `RSCP` is unknown so i can not calculate Ec/No.
4. `SINR = 1 / (1 / 12 . RSRQ) - x`, where `x = RE / RB`, Resource Element `RE` and Resource Block `RB` are unknown. Both RE and RB are unknown.

Should i need to write native code to find/calculate these values or is their any other way to achieve this?

Comment: hii. did you find calculation of SINR for lte? if you find can you please tell the process? Thank you.